# Hide the Sender Address

Tags: anonymity

In ETH system, is it possible to hide the sender address of transactions by 3th party, "zk-SNARK" or others? And if yes, any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Not possible... (and what do you mean with "by 3th party"?).

Comment: 3th party means that other backend services. and could you explain the cause for 'not possible'? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have previously answered a similar question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/80414/16043). I believe that this answer also applies for your question.

Comment: Does it answer your question then?

Comment: I find another article shows that can shield the transaction sender, recipient and the amount. how about your opinion? https://medium.com/@atvanguard/zkdai-private-dai-transactions-on-ethereum-using-zk-snarks-9e3ef4676e22

Comment: Not within the blockchain itself AFAIK.

Comment: You should look at anonymous zether from jp Morgan. It's provides anonymous and confidential transactions. https://github.com/jpmorganchase/anonymous-zether